# Bayesian ARIMA model in Python

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, prediction, bayesian

In reaction to [Sorry ARIMA, but I'm going Bayesian](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/)
I was searching the Internet for a while but could not find any material regarding Bayesian ARIMA models in Python. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: There is [pymc](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/), which is a general package for Bayesian modelling in python. Specifically for time series, there is [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) by facebook, which I think also does something Bayesian under the hood. And there is also [TensorFlow probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/) if you are used to TensorFlow.

Comment: Thank you! I'll surely take a look

Comment: pystan is also a neat tool for Bayesian inference in python. Check out Chapter 10 of the 'Stan User Guide' for good examples.

Comment: Did you have a further look at the options? Anything that stood out as particularly good?

Comment: @nick Thanks!
In my opinion the number one option is pymc3.
Prophet looked really good at first but than I got a feeling that it is rather a black box. I was not able to adjust as I wanted.
Finally I came across pydlm which is package for dynamic linear models which is preatty neat and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. Thats helpful to know :)